# Add Xcode Target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm not sure why this is so difficult/hard to find any documentation for but I'm trying to add an initial target to a scheme for my workspace.

I created a new workspace, added some files, made a new scheme named "Default" but when I try to use it I get the error code "Scheme Default is not currently configured for the build action."

I can't find any docs on how to add a target. Target is grayed out in File > New > Target and when I try to add one with the "+" button in the "Edit Scheme" menu it just shows an empty list with a search option that is obviously going to be blank.

I've heard that Xcode is a nightmare to work with but I can't understand why I can't just add a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add a new `Target` to an existing `Project`. If you start with a `Workspace`, it has no projects in it.

- Go to File -> New and select Project...
- Select the type of Project (such as Single View App)
- Give your project a Name, and specify options (Team, Organization, Language, etc)
- Select Next, and you're presented with a Where to Create window
- At the bottom you should see an option for Add To:

[image]

From that drop-down, select your current Workspace

[image]

In this image, I already have `HelloCpp` project open, and I have `wkplace` Workspace open.

If I choose `wkplace`, this new project will be added to my Workspace and the Project and Target will be automatically added.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the full step-by-step.

New empty Workspace - named `WorkSpace1`:

[image]

Selected File -> New -> Project... then Selected Single View App, clicked Next:

[image]

Entered `MyNewApp` as the Product Name and clicked Next:

[image]

Selected `WorkSpace1` from the `Add To:` drop-down, and clicked Create:

[image]

And I'm taken back to my WorkSpace1 window, with the new Project and Target showing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, unfortunately even after adding a project I still can't add a Target. It is still grayed out as before.

Comment: Also there was no target created with the new project.

Comment: You followed those steps? Was a new Project created - `projname.xcodeproj`?

Comment: Yup. I have a new project and still no Target.

Comment: Hmmm... I edited my answer with step-by-step screen caps. Failing that, you can drag your `projname.xcodeproj` file from Finder into the Navigator pane of your open Workspace... It should bring its "target" with it.

Comment: Awesome, so the problem was when I created a project and added it to the Workspace the default Grouping was going to a folder inside my workspace. I just installed XCode so I'm not sure if that is supposed to be like that but either way the screen shots showed me what was off. Thanks again!

Comment: These instructions are for a single view app. What if you select the "empty" project option? How do you get a target?